Xunit Snaphooter tests return different values when running and debuging
I am using .NET 8.0 for my test project with Xunit, Snaphooter and Moq NuGet packages.
I have noticed that then running my tests the pass but when I start them via Debug I get a failed result.
How can I make the results for running and debugging test match?

We'll need more information than that before we can help you. Please edit the post so that it includes a minimal reproducible example.

Please, narrow down your problem to one unit test, that fails and share it.

@MichałTurczyn How do you know that the problem is related to only a single unit test, instead of interaction of two or more tests?

Error found - when initiating new ExcelPackage this error was thrown
Please set the ExcelPackage.LicenseContext property. See https://epplussoftware.com/developers/licenseexception
After visiting provided link decided to add NonCommercial license to appsettings as provided in the website.
